# Doctrine merging entity with unidirectional OneToMany not clearing database entries

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4

First off, I use Doctrine v2.6.2 with Symfony v4.1.7.

I have an entity `Product` which (among others) has a unidirectional one-to-many relation with another entity `AlternativeDuration`. Following Doctrine's documentation, the mapping in my product class looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(
 *     targetEntity="AlternativeDuration",
 *     cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"},
 *     orphanRemoval=true
 *   )
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ProductAlternativeDurations",
 *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="alternative_duration_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)}
 * )
 */
 protected $alternativeDurations;
```

My application recently started using React, this means I now submit a JSON representation of my product (along with an array of alternative durations) which I need to deserialize into the `Product` entity in the back-end. I use the JMS serializer with default configuration for this.

Now the problem I'm having happens when editing an existing product, the product already has an alternative duration which I delete. The submitted JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,                      # the ID of the existing product here
    "alternativeDurations": []    # empty array because the entry is removed
}
```

In the back-end I successfully deserialize the JSON string:

```
$serializedProduct = $this->serializer->deserialize($jsonString, Product::class, 'json');
```

I verified here that the `$serializedProduct` has no alternative durations. Then I follow with a merge + flush. I expect the merge to fetch the existing product and supplement it with the `$serializedProduct`.

```
$em->merge($serializedProduct);    # $em being the EntityManager.
$em->flush();
```

Now I would expect the `AlternativeDuration` entry, along with the `ProductAlternativeDurations` join table entry being removed. The result, however, is that the entry in `ProductAlternativeDurations` is removed but the `AlternativeDuration` is still there.

I'm at a loss now, anyone can give some pointers on why the `AlternativeDuration` entry is not deleted?

**EDIT 19-11-2018:**

It seems this is a known bug in Doctrine: [#2542](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2542)

Also `merge` will be removed in Doctrine3 so I will probably need to rethink this approach in general.